# Does the training data for a CNN need to be the same size?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

According to the example given on [this blogpost on wildml](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/) (see image below), it seems like it makes no difference what size the input because the size of the max-pooling layer is constant.

[image]

However, I swear I've heard people talk about various methods of normalizing input images by rescaling and cropping so that they are the same size. Would that be purely for the purpose of mini-batching? Or, is the pooling layer above a special case which allows uneven input sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, CNNs typically use same-size input.

If you take a closer at step 3 in that blog posting:

> 3. Pad each sentence to the maximum sentence length, which turns out to
>      be 59. We append special  tokens to all other sentences to make
>      them 59 words. Padding sentences to the same length is useful because
>      it allows us to efficiently batch our data since each example in a
>      batch must be of the same length.

You will see they are using fixed size input there as well.

For text processing in general, it is common to preprocess your data with word-embeddings. Methods such as tf-idf, word2vec and doc2vec take your words/text and provide fixed size numerical input.

Comment: You only need to use inputs of the same size if you want to batch them together during training, otherwise you could have variable input size I believe.